# How to mirror an iPhone map in a web page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance

Basically I want to send gps coordinates (displayed on a map in the iPhone) from the iPhone to a webserver that store the values in a database. You should then be able to retrieve these coordinates and display them on a web page.
I am thinking of a set up like this:

[image]

I want the browser to request and receive the coordinates in real time (every 10 seconds or so) and **I'm wondering if this is a good way to mirror the map in a browser or should I use a different approach? Finally, can you see any obvious flaw/flaws in this design (i.e. performance issues)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your setup makes sense. The question is, what will you use to keep the map in the browser up to date? I would suggest you check out http://socket.io, I think it will do exactly what you need.

Cheers,

Johannes

Comment: I was thinking of setting a timer that makes ajax calls to the server. socket.io seem to be som kind of abstraction of that? I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Yes, so socket.io basically brings WebSockets (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets) to all browsers (even those that don't support it). WebSockets can keep a socket from a browser to a server open without polling. So it's faster, easier and more elegant. Note, however, that Firefox and Opera have disabled WebSockets by default for now because of security concerns.